# how can I have max dates to all values?

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to get from a "queue" table the date values for each element

from a table (only showing top 30)

```
element                     added                   processed
order-confirmation          2013-07-03 14:12:02 2013-07-03 14:12:03
virtual-product-splitter    2013-07-03 14:12:02 2013-07-03 14:12:07
fraud-protect           2013-07-03 14:12:02 2013-07-03 14:12:11
giftcard-creator            2013-07-03 14:12:02 2013-07-03 14:12:15
code-dispatcher         2013-07-03 14:12:02 0001-01-01 00:00:00
order-confirmation          2013-07-03 14:10:01 2013-07-03 14:10:02
virtual-product-splitter    2013-07-03 14:10:01 2013-07-03 14:10:06
fraud-protect           2013-07-03 14:10:01 2013-07-03 14:10:10
giftcard-creator            2013-07-03 14:10:01 2013-07-03 14:10:14
code-dispatcher         2013-07-03 14:10:01 2013-07-03 14:10:19
order-confirmation          2013-07-03 14:08:01 2013-07-03 14:08:02
virtual-product-splitter    2013-07-03 14:08:01 2013-07-03 14:08:05
fraud-protect           2013-07-03 14:08:01 2013-07-03 14:08:09
giftcard-creator            2013-07-03 14:08:01 2013-07-03 14:08:13
code-dispatcher         2013-07-03 14:08:01 2013-07-03 14:08:18
code-dispatcher         2013-07-03 14:06:02 2013-07-03 14:06:19
order-confirmation          2013-07-03 14:06:01 2013-07-03 14:06:02
virtual-product-splitter    2013-07-03 14:06:01 2013-07-03 14:06:06
fraud-protect           2013-07-03 14:06:01 2013-07-03 14:06:10
giftcard-creator            2013-07-03 14:06:01 2013-07-03 14:06:14
order-confirmation          2013-07-03 14:04:02 2013-07-03 14:04:03
virtual-product-splitter    2013-07-03 14:04:02 2013-07-03 14:04:07
fraud-protect           2013-07-03 14:04:02 2013-07-03 14:04:11
giftcard-creator            2013-07-03 14:04:02 2013-07-03 14:04:15
code-dispatcher         2013-07-03 14:04:02 2013-07-03 14:04:19
order-confirmation          2013-07-03 14:02:01 2013-07-03 14:02:03
virtual-product-splitter    2013-07-03 14:02:01 2013-07-03 14:02:06
fraud-protect           2013-07-03 14:02:01 2013-07-03 14:02:10
giftcard-creator            2013-07-03 14:02:01 2013-07-03 14:02:14
code-dispatcher         2013-07-03 14:02:01 2013-07-03 14:02:19
```

doing

`select distinct element from sr_queue` I get

```
'c5-code-integration'
'c5-debitor-integration'
'c5-order-integration'
'c5-product-integration'
'code-dispatcher'
'fraud-protect'
'giftcard-creator'
'order-confirmation'
'packaged-confirmation'
'virtual-product-splitter'
```

and I'm trying to attach the max date (as there's several) to each element, but doing

```
select element, max(added), processed
from sr_queue 
where element in (
   'c5-code-integration',
   'c5-debitor-integration',
   'c5-order-integration',
   'c5-product-integration',
   'code-dispatcher',
   'fraud-protect',
   'giftcard-creator',
   'order-confirmation',
   'packaged-confirmation',
   'virtual-product-splitter')
```

how should I create the selection?

so I can get:

```
order-confirmation          2013-07-03 14:12:02 2013-07-03 14:12:03
virtual-product-splitter    2013-07-03 14:12:02 2013-07-03 14:12:07
fraud-protect               2013-07-03 14:12:02 2013-07-03 14:12:11
giftcard-creator            2013-07-03 14:12:02 2013-07-03 14:12:15
code-dispatcher             2013-07-03 14:12:02 0001-01-01 00:00:00
c5-code-integration         2013-07-03 14:12:02 2013-07-03 14:12:15
...
```

I'm completely blanked after 3 days working on code :(

Comment: mysql, ms sql server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select element, max(added), max(processed)
from sr_queue 
group by element
```

EDIT:

```
select element, added, processed
from sr_queue q
where added = (SELECT MAX(added) FROM sr_queue s WHERE s.element = q.element)
```

Or another possibility:

```
SELECT element, added, processed
FROM sr_queue s 
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT element, MAX(added)
   FROM sr_queue 
   GROUP BY element
) q ON s.element = q.element
```

Comment: I want to get the `processed` value of the same row of `max(added)`, is that possible?

Comment: that's extremely expensive in terms of process... need to find a better way... in a 425000 rows, that takes more than 10 min :/

Comment: I assume you're missing an index, then. Please have a look at this question and my answer on it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358578/whats-the-canonical-way-to-pull-a-record-from-a-mysql-database-that-has-a-least/17360946#17360946 It's for MySQL but also suitable for SQL Server or whatever you're using, since it's standard SQL.

Comment: @balexandre Have you tried adding an index? I'm sure your query will then run in under 1 second. And the way I did is the usual way to solve this problem.

Comment: that will return all rows ... don't worry, I have made a 2nd call to the database and works... thought I would love to know how to do both in the db itself.

Answer (score 3):

Use `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT
     element,
     MAX(added)
FROM
    sr_queue
GROUP BY
    element
```

Comment: see, really tired ... "GROUP BY" arrghhhhhh! what, wait... this way I will never get the `processed` row of the `MAX(added)`, how do I do that?

Comment: What database engine do you use? SQL Server, MySQL, other one?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a recent version of MS SQL Server

```
 select element, added, processed from
 (select *, row_number() over (partition by element order by added desc) as ranker
 from sr_queue q ) Z
 where ranker = 1
```